# Trading View: how to use the fields from invite-only indicator, inside of my custom pine-script study?

Tags: pine-script

I am using an "**invite-only**" script, as a custom indicator. When the script is applied on the chart and I manually try to add an alert over this script, I can see there are some related fields which I can manage on the alert dialog. What I want to accomplish is to write a `pine-script` study where I will be able to call `alertcondition(condition, title, message)` and inside of the condition to use the custom fields which are indicator specific only. Considering that I don't have access to the code of the indicator, I can not alter the code from the "**invite-only**" script.

Is there any way which I can use the indicator related fields for creating the alert condition inside of my `pine-script` study? Any link / reference will be helpful, as I was not able to find any so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another indicator as an input source.

```
data = input(title="Data", type=input.source, defval=close)
```

In the `Data` input dropdown, you should see the names of the plots of the invite-only indicator.
From there on, you can use that value in an alert.
For details, see [How to code an input option for TradingView's ‘apply indicator on indicator’ feature?](https://kodify.net/tradingview/inputs/code-input-apply-indicator/)

Comment: yes, but this doesnt give the coder access to the source inside pine editor, you have to apply the indicator to the chart to use the datasource

Comment: Of course. The author decides who can see the source code.

Comment: @BjornMistiaen what if I have more the one series (from the private indicator) which I want to use? With the approach you listed, I have access to one series (into the variable `data`), but I need to have access to a few of them. If I rename the title "Data" (from `title="Data"` part) into some other name, as input options for this filed, it gives me only the default values  like `open, high, low, close, hl2, hlc3, ohlc4` and in that case, I am not able to select the custom series from my private indicator. So is there a way to get more of the series by using the input fields as you listed?

Comment: The title "Data" has nothing to do with what you can select. It's just a title. You could copy the line and make a `data2 = input(title="Data2", type=input.source, defval=close)`. If you've added the closed source indicator to your chart, you should be able to pick it's outputs in the dropdowns of your `data` input variables.

Comment: @BjornMistiaen is there a way I can use the custom indicator as defval?